# Sliding window in R for dates

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I am working on a project that requires me to create a flag field if an item has `n` number of occurrences (**on different dates**) within a 30-day window (for each `TYPE`). If it did occur `n` times within the window then it would flag all of the relevant dates with `1` and if it did not occur then the dates would be `0`.

My data looks something like this:

```
a <- data.frame("TYPE" = c("A", "A", "B", "B",
                           "C", "C", "C", "C",
                           "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
                "DATE" = c("4/20/2018 11:47",
                           "4/25/2018 7:21",
                           "4/15/2018 6:11",
                           "4/19/2018 4:22",
                           "4/15/2018 17:46",
                           "4/16/2018 11:59",
                           "4/20/2018 7:50",
                           "4/26/2018 2:55",
                           "4/27/2018 11:46",
                           "4/27/2018 13:03",
                           "4/20/2018 7:31",
                           "4/22/2018 9:45"))
```

After sorting first by `TYPE` and then by `DATE` and then saying `n <- 4` this would be my expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

It is important to note that there will be multiple dates that are the same date for a type, and this will need a rolling/moving window for each `TYPE`.

I am looking for assistance with how to approach this problem.

Would I be able to use the [SlidingWindow](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/evobiR/versions/1.1/topics/SlidingWindow) function in R and then define my own function?

Comment: yes thats one way and one of the ones i was getting ready to show you before the edit ;) right on

Comment: Why is `D` not 1? Four occurrences within just-over 7 days.

Comment: @r2evans it is 4 occurances, however, not on different dates.

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr::inner_join` based approach could be as:

```
library(dplyr)

a %>% mutate(DATE = as.POSIXct(DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
inner_join(.,., by="TYPE") %>%
  group_by(TYPE, DATE.x) %>%
  summarise(FLAG = as.integer(sum(abs((DATE.x-DATE.y)/(24*60*60))<=30)>=4))
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
# # Groups: TYPE [?]
# TYPE   DATE.x               FLAG
# <fctr> <dttm>              <int>
# 1 A      2018-04-20 11:47:00     0
# 2 A      2018-04-25 07:21:00     0
# 3 B      2018-04-15 06:11:00     0
# 4 B      2018-04-19 04:22:00     0
# 5 C      2018-04-15 17:46:00     1
# 6 C      2018-04-16 11:59:00     1
# 7 C      2018-04-20 07:50:00     1
# 8 C      2018-04-26 02:55:00     1
# 9 D      2018-04-20 07:31:00     1
# 10 D      2018-04-22 09:45:00     1
# 11 D      2018-04-27 11:46:00     1
# 12 D      2018-04-27 13:03:00     1
```

**Note:** The 4 records for `TYPE = D` are also within 30 days range. Hence, FLAG should be set as `1` for `TYPE D` as well.

Comment: How would you address the 4 different dates aspect? In this answer it flags `D` incorrectly, since `D` has 4 dates but not 4 different dates.

Comment: Do you mean to ignore if date is same? If so then we can handle that as well. Another small query. Do you want to consider only date or even time while considering difference of a day? as your data got time as well.

Comment: In the case of D it would flag 0 since the last 2 dates are the same day. However, if we added 1 more date to D say 4/28/2018 9:45 then it should flag all of the D fields because 1) all of those dates fall within 30-day window and 2) there are 4 or more individual dates within a 30-day window.